# Was "I Dream of Jeannie"'s rating drop due to the marriage, or did it start before?

Tags: audience-measurement, i-dream-of-jeannie

It is commonly acknowledged that after the two main characters married, *I Dream of Jeannie* had [heavy rating drops that led to the show's cancellation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qv4t0EgCe_g) in 1970. However, I am wondering: was the show already suffering low ratings and the marriage plotline a desperate attempt to revive it, or were the ratings doing fine before the marriage?

Answer (score 8):

> However, I am wondering: was the show already suffering low ratings and the marriage plotline a desperate attempt to revive it, or were the ratings doing fine before the marriage?

It should be understood that *I Dream of Jeannie* wasn't a massive ratings hit at any point in its five-year TV history.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Dream_of_Jeannie#Nielsen_ratings) indicates that for 3 of its seasons it wasn't in the top 30 rated shows and for the other two its highest position was 26th.

[image]

It could be argued that the network intended that the marriage in the fifth (and eventual final) season would *boost* ratings on a relatively mediocre rated show but most people involved with the production considered the idea a mistake as it ruined the sexual tension between the two main stars.

The wedding episode did, apparently, garner high ratings as an individual episode but the stories (it was considered) were poor and ratings dropped as a result.

Consequently, the show was cancelled more as a *result* of the marriage than anything else.